# Guru, how to fix [Error] Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'

Tags: reactjs, autoprefixer

PS C:\Users\TUF GAMING USER\Desktop\Portfolio Agency\portfolio> npm run start

> portfolio@0.1.0 start
> vite

VITE v4.3.9  ready in 462 ms

➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose
➜  press h to show help
node:internal/process/promises:288
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

[Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: C:/Users/TUF GAMING USER/Desktop/Portfolio Agency/portfolio): [Error] Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\TUF GAMING USER\Desktop\Portfolio Agency\portfolio\postcss.config.js

(@C:\Users\TUF GAMING USER\Desktop\Portfolio Agency\portfolio\postcss.config.js)
Error: Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\TUF GAMING USER\Desktop\Portfolio Agency\portfolio\postcss.config.js

(@C:\Users\TUF GAMING USER\Desktop\Portfolio Agency\portfolio\postcss.config.js)
at load (file:///C:/Users/TUF%20GAMING%20USER/Desktop/Portfolio%20Agency/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:36333:11)
at file:///C:/Users/TUF%20GAMING%20USER/Desktop/Portfolio%20Agency/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:36358:16
at Array.map ()
at plugins (file:///C:/Users/TUF%20GAMING%20USER/Desktop/Portfolio%20Agency/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:36357:8)
at processResult (file:///C:/Users/TUF%20GAMING%20USER/Desktop/Portfolio%20Agency/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:36427:14)
at file:///C:/Users/TUF%20GAMING%20USER/Desktop/Portfolio%20Agency/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:36551:14]

Node.js v18.13.0
PS C:\Users\TUF GAMING USER\Desktop\Portfolio Agency\portfolio>

I cannot fix this issue if any can fix this error please tell me thank you so much